# Array of tokenized string literals in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, tokenize

I'm writing a C program to tokenize an input text file and track the frequency of word length, alongside tracking and storing the corresponding words themselves. I have the word count working fine, but can't get my word_tracker array to store the strings correctly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 34
#define MAX_WORDS 750

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 

    FILE *fp; //input file
    const char *cur; //stores current word as string literal
    char words[MAX_LENGTH*MAX_WORDS]; //stores all words from text file
    char file_name[100]; //stores file name
    int word_count[MAX_LENGTH] = {0}; //array to store frequency of words based on length
    const char *word_tracker[MAX_LENGTH][MAX_WORDS]; //array to store string literals of each word, indexed by char count and 
    int char_count; //current word's char count

    printf("Enter a file name: ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); 

    if((fp==NULL)){
        printf("Failure: missing or unopenable file");
        return -1; 
    }else{
        while(fgets(words, sizeof(words), fp)){
            cur= strtok(words, " -.,\b\t\n"); //first word of line
            char_count = strlen(cur);
            word_count[char_count-1] = word_count[char_count-1]+1; //increment frequency of specific word length
            word_tracker[char_count-1][word_count[char_count-1]-1] = cur; //store string into corresponding array index location

            /*test printing*/
            printf("%d:", char_count-1); 
            printf("%s ", word_tracker[char_count-1][(word_count[char_count-1])-1]); 

            while(cur){
                    cur = strtok(NULL, " -.,\b\t\n"); //next word
                    if(cur){
                        char_count = strlen(cur);
                        word_count[char_count-1] = word_count[char_count-1]+1; //increment frequency of specific word length
                        word_tracker[char_count-1][word_count[char_count-1]-1] = cur; //store string into corresponding array index location

                        /*test printing*/
                        printf("%d:", char_count-1); //test print
                        printf("%s ", word_tracker[char_count-1][(word_count[char_count-1])-1]); //test print

                    }
                }
            }
        }
//Testing word_tracker: (This doesn't work)
    printf("\n\n%s \n", word_tracker[0][0]);
    printf("\n%s \n", word_tracker[1][0]);
    printf("%s \n", word_tracker[2][0]);
    printf("%s \n", word_tracker[3][0]);
    printf("%s \n", word_tracker[4][0]);
    printf("%s \n", word_tracker[5][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The "interior" tests (within the tokenizing loop) work well, the correct string and length are printed. However, the print tests at the end of main print seemingly random strings, relative to what the input text file says they should input. I have three theories on what I am doing wrong:

1) My indexing is wrong

2) My understand of how to populate and use char* arrays is incorrect

3) My tokenizing loop is incorrect (does cur not equal "the isolated string"?)

I've noticed that the tests at the end of main display variants of whatever is written on the final line of the input file, so I think that my tokenizing loop is likely wrong. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: hi ben, please don't take it the wrong way, but your code is a hot mess :P you need to break things down into bits of functions so that you (and others) can follow it easily.

Comment: You want to store a 2D array of chars, but `const char *word_tracker[MAX_LENGTH][MAX_WORDS];` is a *pointer* to a 2D array of  chars, remove the `*` in the declaration, and notice that you need `const char word_tracker[MAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH];` instead of `const char word_tracker[MAX_LENGTH][MAX_WORDS];`, finaly, `const` makes your array not writeable (read only), remove the `const` part :)

Comment: Yes and no, @KeineLust.  The OP's original declaration of `word_tracker` is not a pointer to a 2D array, but rather a 2D array of pointers.  A pointer to a 2D array would be `const char (*word_tracker)[MAX_LENGTH][MAX_WORDS]` (note the added parentheses).

Comment: @KeineLust It seems to me that the OP is trying to create a 2D array of *strings*, where word[i][j] is the string number j of length i.

Comment: @AhmedMasud none taken, are you asking me to split my main() into actual functions, or simply better lay it out within main?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you are right!

Comment: @Bob__ That is correct

Comment: I think splitting the code up into functions is a good idea. give it a go, it may even help you solve the problem :P perhaps even come up with a better design for it. if you're struggling after a good attempt I will give you a walk through on a reasonable approach to this problem :P

Comment: Consider using [`strcspn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) (which returns the length of initial substring) instead of `strtok`.

Comment: 1. Run inside a debugger (gdb)

2. Run with sanitizer options turned on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result array currently is `const char *word_tracker[MAX_LENGTH][MAX_WORDS]`, which is a 2D-array of *pointers*.
You could either (a) use a 1D-array of pointers and allocate memory then for each word found, or (b) use a 2D-array of characters and `strcpy` each word at the proper position.

So (a) would look like...

```
const char *word_tracker[MAX_WORDS];
...
word_tracker[someIndexWithSomeMeaningUpToMAX_WORDS] = strdup(cur);
```

And (b) would look like

```
char word_tracker[MAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH];
...
strncpy(word_tracker[someIndexWithSomeMeaningUpToMAX_WORDS], cur, MAX_LENGTH);
word_tracker[someIndexWithSomeMeaningUpToMAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH-1] = '\0'
```

Note that in (b), `MAX_LENGTH` indicates the maximum length of a string (i.e. a single word) and is therefore the second index. `strncpy` makes sure not to exceed the size reserved for a word.

Comment: `const char word_tracker[MAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH];
strncpy(word_tracker[someIndexWithSomeMeaningUpToMAX_WORDS], cur, MAX_LENGTH);` ---> "passing argument 1 of 'strncpy' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]"